# \def, math, and order of operations, expansion?

Tags: math-mode, expansion, lengths

I have what looks like a simple task but I cannot seem to get it to work.

take the following:

```
\def\varlength{1in}%has units
\def\varscalar{0.2}%does not have units

\raisebox{\varscalar\varlength}[0pt][0pt]{hello}%
```

Everything works fine. But this doesn't. Note the change in `\varscalar`:

```
\def\varlength{1in}%has units
\def\varscalar{{1-0.8}}%does not have units

\raisebox{\varscalar\varlength}[0pt][0pt]{hello}%
```

I do not understand why the extra `{}` do not force the `1-0.8` to evaluate before multiplication of `\varscalar` and `\varlength`.

I need to either ensure the `1-0.8` happens before this multiplication, or even better would be to occur before the expansion of `\varscalar`. I would think the second of these options to be more efficient and better.

---

Forgot the MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}


\begin{document}


\def\varlength{1in}%has units
\def\varscalar{0.2}%does not have units

hi
\raisebox{\varscalar\varlength}[0pt][0pt]{hello}%


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to somehow parse/evaluate the expression that you pass to `\varscalar`. There are tons of possible ways, such as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}
\newlength\varlength
\begin{document}
\varlength=1in%has units
\def\varscalar{\fpeval{1-0.8}}%does not have units

\raisebox{\the\dimexpr\varscalar\varlength+\varscalar\varlength}[0pt][0pt]{hello}%
\end{document}
```

`\the\dimexpr` is not needed here but it would allow you to add linear combinations, e.g.

```
\raisebox{\the\dimexpr\varscalar\varlength+\varscalar\varlength}[0pt][0pt]{hello}%
```

This answer was updated to include making `\varlength` a length from [David Carlisle's answer below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/517298/194703).
My take on the question was to answer

> I do not understand why the extra {} do not force the 1-0.8 to
>   evaluate

and not the fact that a macro is not a dimension (which I assumed, perhaps wrongly, to be obvious).

Comment: You don't need `\the` in either place. But this does not work, because it would raise by `0.21in`, not by `0.2in`. If you try with `\def\varlength{0.5in}` you'll see.

Comment: @egreg Thanks! But AFAIK it does not hurt here and there are more than enough rather similar situations in which you need it, so I tend to add it.

Comment: With `\def\varlength{1in}` and `\def\varscalar{2}`, you get `21in` instead of `2in`.

Comment: @egreg Sure. The question is why the OP's attempt does not work, not how to raise something in the most elegant way. The answer to the latter question would not use any of this. I think it is understood that `\def\varlength{1in}` does not create a length but just a macro.

Comment: If I could re-ask the question, I would delete everything and ask why doesnt `{1-0.8}1in` evaluate to `0.2in`.

Comment: @Bob Because this is not really foreseen by TeX, which is rather ancient system. In very basic TeX, you can add and multiply (and divide) but not parse some more complicated expressions such as `(a+b)*c`. Of course, there exist many packages that allow you to do that, but at the built-in level you cannot use/parse/evaluate the more complicated terms. If you use `\varlength` as a length then `\the\dimexpr1\varlength-0.2\varlength` will be understood correctly.

Comment: @egreg Following your comment and David's answer I changed `\varlength` to become a length. As I said, to me the question was on "I do not understand why the extra {} do not force the 1-0.8 to evaluate", which I correctly answer and answered in all versions.

Comment: honestly your answer made more sense before you changed it.

Comment: I do not understand why one would write `\dimexpr\varscalar\varlength`. Does `\dimexpr` take a length or a scalar as an argument?

Comment: @Bob `\dimexpr` looks at comes after and parses until it sees something that tells it how it should stop parsing. This something is typically a `}` or a `\relax` or something of that sort. In this case here you do not even need it, `\raisebox{\varscalar\varlength}[0pt][0pt]{hello}` will also work, but not `\raisebox{\varscalar\varlength+\varscalar\varlength}[0pt][0pt]{hello}`. Please note that `\dimexpr` was not part of the original TeX system, but was added later by a famous physicist (if I remember things correctly).

Answer (score 3):

With your code, you get `0.21in` when TeX does expansion, which is not what you want. It's close, but just by chance.

If you try with

```latex
\def\varlength{1in}
\def\varscalar{2}
```

the amount of raising would be 21in. TeX just expands tokens.

You can do, instead

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\def\varlength{1in}%has units
\def\varscalar{0.2}%does not have units

hi
\raisebox{\varscalar\dimexpr\varlength\relax}[0pt][0pt]{hello}

\the\dimexpr\varlength\relax

\the\dimexpr\varscalar\dimexpr\varlength\relax

\end{document}
```

so `\varlength` is made into an unnamed dimension register and the expansion would be

```latex
\raisebox{0.2\dimexpr1in\relax}
```

that's what you'd like.

For arithmetic with floating point numbers, combine this with what's has already been suggested, namely `\fpeval`.

Comment: Can you provide the definition of `\dimexpr`? I cannot seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: @Bob It's a primitive, it has no definition.

Comment: Finding how to use tex primitives is one of the most difficult tasks. I dont know why but I cant seem to find a comprehensive source for them, like the oracle for java, something that tells what to pass and what to expect and what options are available.

Answer (score 3):

You say  that this works fine

```
   \def\varlength{1in}%has units
   \def\varscalar{0.2}%does not have unit

   \raisebox{\varscalar\varlength}[0pt][0pt]{hello}%
```

But from the names I would expect that you want 0.2in as the effective length but the macros simply expand, no multiplication takes place and so you get `0.21in` which happens to be a legal length, but had the original length been say, `0.5in` then `\varscalar\varlength` would be `0.20.5in` and a syntax error.

What you should have is

```
\newlength\varlength
\setlength\varlength{1in}
```

then  `\varscalar\varlength` would be `0.2\varlength` that is `0.2in`.

It isn't clear what is your expectation with

```
\def\varscalar{{1-0.8}}
```

as it can not work whatever definition you give for `\varlength`

If `\varlength` is a macro then `\varscalar\varlength` expands to `{1-0.8}1in`  which is not a legal length,

and if `\varlength` is a length register then  `\varscalar\varlength` expands to `{1-0.8}\varlength`  which is again a syntax error.

perhaps declare `\varlength` as a register then use `\dimexpr\varlength - 0.8\varlength\relax`

Comment: So how do you do basic math in tex then? I dont see why `{1-0.8}1in` would not evaluate to `{0.2}1in` and then to `0.1in`.

Comment: @Bob classic tex has no inline arithmetic expressions at all, etex adds `\numexpr` for integer expressions, there ie no floating point so you can not evaluate 1-0.8 but there is as I show `\dimexpr` so you can do `\dimexpr\varlength - 0.8\varlength\relax`

Comment: @Bob I can't think of any programming language where `{0.2}1` is multiplication, so even if Tex had floating point values that could be multiplied I think it highly unlikely that would be the syntax. Actually when I originally wrote this answer it had not even guessed that you mean multiplication here, I didn't know what you wanted it to do at all. I added the final "perhaps.. line with the working expression at the end after I realised what calculation you wanted

Comment: In tex I see a lot of cases like this, `0.7\baseline` or `0.7\linewidth` where the macro is some sort of dimensioned variable. I tried to repeat that with \varscalar\varlength.

Comment: @Bob yes that's the syntax you can use with a dimen register, as I show here but you can't  do `{0.7}\linewidth`